# Sending Gmail using EmailJsl using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a contact Html Page for people to contact me . I'm using EmailJs service
While I'm using this code it works without put it inside a function but ...... When I put it inside the function it doesn't work !! How can I fix it ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@emailjs/browser@3/dist/email.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        emailjs.init('Public_Key');    
        emailjs.send("Service_ID","Template_ID",{
                        from_name: 'abdullah',
                        from_email: "example@gmail.com",
                        message: 'Hi',
                        })
```

**I filled out the correct keys and ID**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It seems you're sharing the code that works, it would be more helpful to share the piece with the snippet that doesn't work, especially to allow people to see how and when you invoke that function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.